# Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given a string like:

```
"The dog      has a long   tail, and it     is RED!"
```

What kind of jQuery or JavaScript magic can be used to keep spaces to only one space max?

Goal:

```
"The dog has a long tail, and it is RED!"
```

Comment: Do you also want to match whitespacy tab characters?

Comment: @Chris, Yes please, great question.... With all these different answers, how is one supposed to know which is the most efficient solution?

Comment: Everyone below is right, but this is the most optimized regex: `str.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');` you're not replacing anything you don't have to.

Comment: There's not going to be any noticeable difference in performance. You could always profile it, but I doubt it would be worth it. I would go for the clearest.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Not true -- at least on Firefox.  That version runs significantly slower.  See the profiling results in my answer (below).

Comment: Grammarly would love this!

Answer (score 1385, accepted):

Given that you also want to cover tabs, newlines, etc, just replace `\s\s+` with `' '`:

```
string = string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
```

If you really want to cover only spaces (and thus not tabs, newlines, etc), do so:

```
string = string.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Does this also remove, whitespacy tab characters?

Comment: @nobosh: yes, it replaces all white-space characters (space, tab, \r, \n, \v \f) with space-character.

Comment: This is not working when a blank instead of a tab or newline is needed. Right? /\s+/ would be working.

Comment: it would might be better for you as a function such as `function removeExtraSpaces(string){ return string.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');}`

Comment: Oracle version: 

SELECT regexp_replace('abc    def     a', '\s\s+', ' ')
  FROM DUAL

Comment: This doesn't remove the initial and trailing whitespaces. For that see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258021/235415).

Comment: @Ethan: JS has a builtin function for that: `trim()`. It's faster than regex. You could just do `string.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');` or `string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim();`.

Comment: `/\s\s+/g` and `/\s{2,}/g` do not match whitespacey characters unless there are at least two adjacent to each other, e.g. will match \t\t but will not match single \t. `string.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` will match all single and multiple whitespacey character substrings and replace with single space.

Comment: @NadavB: if you're referring to the 2nd snippet; a newline is indeed not a space.

Comment: @BalusC: When you replace `/\s+/` with a single space `' '`, you never end up with a sentence with no spaces at all. Am I still missing something?

Comment: @BugsBunny: Sorry, I was not awake. The technical reason is performance. See next answer.

Answer (score 243):

Since you seem to be interested in performance, I profiled these with firebug.  Here are the results I got:

```
str.replace( /  +/g, ' ' )       ->  380ms
str.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' )     ->  390ms
str.replace( / {2,}/g, ' ' )     ->  470ms
str.replace( / +/g, ' ' )        ->  790ms
str.replace( / +(?= )/g, ' ')    -> 3250ms
```

This is on Firefox, running 100k string replacements.

I encourage you to do your own profiling tests with firebug, if you think performance is an issue.  Humans are notoriously bad at predicting where the bottlenecks in their programs lie.

(Also, note that IE 8's developer toolbar also has a profiler built in -- it might be worth checking what the performance is like in IE.)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/removing-multiple-spaces Go forth and JSPerf! The last method; `( / +(?= )/g, ' ');` fails in IE9, it leaves double spaces: `"Foo  Bar   Baz".replace(/ +(?= )/g, ' ');` --> `"Foo  Bar  Baz" `

Comment: @VivekPanday - I imagine that this is because the second line is only replacing occurrences of double spaces with a single space, while the first is replacing any space with a space as well.  Whether this is time saved during the search or the actual replace, I don't know.

Comment: This doesn't remove the initial and trailing whitespaces. For that see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258021/235415).

Comment: None of it worked for a multiline text:

const text = `Your      text     here

a

as     da
das
das
d
asdasd
 KEEP IN NEW LINE NUMBER 1
  as
   da
   s
    
    as.   a asda dfadasd
    
KEEP IN NEW LINE
ALSO KEEP IN NEW LINE`

Answer (score 57):

```
var str = "The      dog        has a long tail,      and it is RED!";
str = str.replace(/ {2,}/g,' ');
```

**EDIT:**
If you wish to replace all kind of whitespace characters the most efficient way would be like that:

```
str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ');
```

Answer (score 18):

A more robust method: This takes care of *also* removing the initial and trailing spaces, if they exist. Eg:

```
// NOTE the possible initial and trailing spaces
var str = "  The dog      has a long   tail, and it     is RED!  "

str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");

// str -> "The dog has a long tail, and it is RED !"
```

Your example didn't have those spaces but they are a very common scenario too, and the accepted answer was only trimming those into single spaces, like: " The ... RED! ", which is not what you will typically need.

Comment: I used this pattern on PHP and works.
$parts = preg_split("/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/", "Avenida Tancredo Neves, 745  Piso Térreo Sala");

Comment: This looks more inefficient than a simple preliminary `.trim()`.

Answer (score 17):

This is one solution, though it will target *all* space characters:

```
"The      dog        has a long tail,      and it is RED!".replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')

"The dog has a long tail, and it is RED!"
```

**Edit**: This is probably better since it targets a space followed by 1 or more spaces:

```
"The      dog        has a long tail,      and it is RED!".replace(/  +/g, ' ')

"The dog has a long tail, and it is RED!"
```

Alternative method:

```
"The      dog        has a long tail,      and it is RED!".replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ')
"The dog has a long tail, and it is RED!"
```

I didn't use `/\s+/` by itself since that replaces spaces that span 1 character multiple times and might be less efficient since it targets more than necessary.

I didn't deeply test any of these so lmk if there are bugs.

Also, if you're going to do string replacement remember to re-assign the variable/property to its own replacement, eg:

```
var string = 'foo'
string = string.replace('foo', '')
```

Using jQuery.prototype.text:

```
var el = $('span:eq(0)');
el.text( el.text().replace(/\d+/, '') )
```

Comment: The first one is totally pointless, \s\s+ means, an \s followed by one or more \s+, which can be reduced to a single \s+, the second example is more accurate because we only want to replace double spaces, not newlines, the third is more optimized because it only applies to examples with 2+ spaces. But str.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');, only applies to examples with 2+ spaces but saves overwriting a space with a space step.

Comment: EvanCarroll you **fail** because \s\s+ is definitely different to \s+. \s\s+ would match '\t\t' or '\t\t\t' but NOT '\t'. And that's what it's all about, you don't want replace every f-en single whitespace character.

Comment: I do. Used for full-text search (and snippet-display): No random tabs, non-breakers or thingymajigs, please.

Answer (score 16):

I have this method, I call it the Derp method for lack of a better name.

```
while (str.indexOf("  ") !== -1) {
    str = str.replace(/  /g, " ");
}
```

Running it in JSPerf gives some surprising results where it beat some of the more sophisticated approaches **EDIT** Original JSPerf link http://jsperf.com/removing-multiple-spaces/3 seems to be dead at the time

Comment: I didn’t downvote this, but this looks inefficient and the JSPerf link is dead that I can’t check out the “_surprising results_.” So I ask you instead: was this _surprising_ enough to be upvoted?

Comment: @КонстантинВан Thanks for pointing out the dead link!

Answer (score 13):

Here is an alternate solution if you do not want to use replace (replace spaces in a string without using replace javascript)

```js
var str="The dog      has a long   tail, and it     is RED!";
var rule=/\s{1,}/g;

str = str.split(rule).join(" "); 

document.write(str);
```

Comment: “_If you do not want to use `replace`_”? Why would one not want to use it? `split`ing and `join`ing is obviously much slower than a `replace` call.

Comment: @КонстантинВан In my case eBay templates restricted the use of replace

Answer (score 10):

More robust:

```
function trim(word)
{
    word = word.replace(/[^\x21-\x7E]+/g, ' '); // change non-printing chars to spaces
    return word.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');      // remove leading/trailing spaces
}
```

Comment: Why would you `replace` to trim when you can `.trim()`?

Answer (score 9):

I suggest

```
string = string.replace(/ +/g," ");
```

for just spaces 
 OR

```
string = string.replace(/(\s)+/g,"$1");
```

for turning multiple returns into a single return also.

Answer (score 6):

Also a possibility:

```
str.replace( /\s+/g, ' ' )
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that I am late to the party, but I discovered a nice solution.

Here it is:

```
var myStr = myStr.replace(/[ ][ ]*/g, ' ');
```

Comment: And how is that different than `/ +/` and `/[ ]+/`?

Answer (score 4):

**Comprehensive unencrypted answer for newbies et al.**

This is for all of the dummies like me who test the scripts written by some of you guys which do not work.

The following 3 examples are the steps I took to remove special characters AND extra spaces on the following 3 websites (all of which work perfectly) {1. EtaVisa.com 2. EtaStatus.com 3. Tikun.com} so I know that these work perfectly.

We have chained these together with over 50 at a time and NO problems.

// This removed special characters + 0-9 and allows for just letters (upper and LOWER case)

```
function NoDoublesPls1()
{
var str=document.getElementById("NoDoubles1");
var regex=/[^a-z]/gi;
str.value=str.value.replace(regex ,"");
}
```

// This removed special characters and allows for just letters (upper and LOWER case) and 0-9 AND spaces

```
function NoDoublesPls2()
{
var str=document.getElementById("NoDoubles2");
var regex=/[^a-z 0-9]/gi;
str.value=str.value.replace(regex ,"");
}
```

// This removed special characters and allows for just letters (upper and LOWER case) and 0-9 AND spaces
// The .replace(/\s\s+/g, " ") at the end removes excessive spaces
// when I used single quotes, it did not work.

```
function NoDoublesPls3()
{    var str=document.getElementById("NoDoubles3");
var regex=/[^a-z 0-9]/gi;
str.value=str.value.replace(regex ,"") .replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
}
```

**::NEXT::**
Save #3 as `a .js` // I called mine NoDoubles.js

**::NEXT::**
Include your JS into your page

```
 <script language="JavaScript" src="js/NoDoubles.js"></script>
```

Include this in your form field:: such as

```
<INPUT type="text" name="Name"
     onKeyUp="NoDoublesPls3()" onKeyDown="NoDoublesPls3()" id="NoDoubles3"/>
```

So that it looks like this

```
<INPUT type="text" name="Name" onKeyUp="NoDoublesPls3()" onKeyDown="NoDoublesPls3()" id="NoDoubles3"/>
```

This will remove special characters, allow for single spaces and remove extra spaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
var string = "The dog      has a long   tail, and it     is RED!";
var replaced = string.replace(/ +/g, " ");
```

Or if you also want to replace tabs:

```
var replaced = string.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

Comment: using + seems cleaner but it will also replace single spaces with single spaces, a little bit redundant and I'm not sure but it may create performace problems with a much longer text.

Comment: I tend to use the shortest, simplest solution that will work, and only worry about that sort of optimization if I know that I need to be matching against a very large string, an at that point I will actually measure different solutions to see which will be faster. It can be hard to predict in advance what will be fastest without testing; for instance, in JavaScript interpreters, some complicated regular expressions will cause you to switch from a fast JIT compiled implementation to a slow interpreted one.

Answer (score 3):

It's as easy as doing:

```
const myString = "  Hello     World       !   "
const parsed = myString.replace(/ +/g, ' ') // " Hello World ! "
```

Now, if you wanna get rid of the starting and ending spaces, you can do:

```
const trimmed = parsed.trim() // "Hello World !"
```

## ONE LINER (TL;DR)

```
const parsedSTring = "   John     Doe    ".replace(/ +/g, ' ').trim() // "John Doe"
```

Answer (score 2):

// replace multiple white spaces with one white space

```
String replacedDisplayName = displayName.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
```

Comment: `\s` means \s stands for “whitespace character”. ... That is: \s matches a space, a tab, a carriage return, a line feed, or a form feed. https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: This doesn't work `'a    b'.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")` -> `'a    b'`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myregexp = new RegExp(/ {2,}/g);

str = str.replace(myregexp,' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = `xxx  df dfvdfv  df    
                     dfv`.split(/[\s,\t,\r,\n]+/).filter(x=>x).join(' ');
```

result:

```
"xxx df dfvdfv df dfv"
```

Comment: Great answer. It removes newline breaks too :)

Comment: First, why would you `split`–`join` when you can do a simple `replace`? Second, **your _character set_ also matches “`,`”.**

Answer (score 0):

I know we have to use regex, but during an interview, I was asked to do WITHOUT USING REGEX.

@slightlytyler helped me in coming with the below approach.

```js
const testStr = "I   LOVE    STACKOVERFLOW   LOL";

const removeSpaces = str  => {
  const chars = str.split('');
  const nextChars = chars.reduce(
    (acc, c) => {
      if (c === ' ') {
        const lastChar = acc[acc.length - 1];
        if (lastChar === ' ') {
          return acc;
        }
      }
      return [...acc, c];
    },
    [],
  );
  const nextStr = nextChars.join('');
  return nextStr
};

console.log(removeSpaces(testStr));
```

Comment: consider: console.log(testStr.split(" ").filter(s => s.length).join(" "))

Comment: @dpjanes thanks, mate, do we have any similar chain function to get "DISTINCT" element from an array, we will be using the same array, no new array

Comment: hahah I love a challenge. Not fully chained, but one line:

console.log(Array.from(new Set("I   LOVE    STACKOVERFLOW   LOL LOVE".split(" ").filter(s => s.length))).join(" "))

Comment: The core concept being Array.from(new Set(<some list>)).

Answer (score 0):

here is my solutions that work well for me:

```js
var text = "    Tes ddas    dMd WAlkman 3Dsfd    "
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\b\s+/g, " ")
    .replace(/\b\w/g, s => s.toUpperCase())
    .trimStart()
    .trimEnd();
    
console.log(text);

// result: Tes Ddas Dmd Walkman 3dsfd
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use the following regex explained with the help of sed system command. The similar regex can be used in other languages and platforms.

Add the text into some file say test

```
manjeet-laptop:Desktop manjeet$ cat test
"The dog      has a long   tail, and it     is RED!"
```

We can use the following regex to replace all white spaces with single space

```
manjeet-laptop:Desktop manjeet$ sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g' test
"The dog has a long tail, and it is RED!"
```

Hope this serves the purpose

Answer (score -1):

Try this to replace multiple spaces with a single space.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myStr = "The dog      has a long   tail, and it     is RED!";
    alert(myStr);  // Output 'The dog      has a long   tail, and it     is RED!'

    var newStr = myStr.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
    alert(newStr);  // Output 'The dog has a long tail, and it is RED!'
</script>
```

Read more @ [Replacing Multiple Spaces with Single Space](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-single-space-using-javascript/)

Comment: A duplicate of the old answer.

Answer (score -1):

For more control you can use the replace callback to handle the value.

```
value = "tags:HUNT  tags:HUNT         tags:HUNT  tags:HUNT"
value.replace(new RegExp(`(?:\\s+)(?:tags)`, 'g'), $1 => ` ${$1.trim()}`)
//"tags:HUNT tags:HUNT tags:HUNT tags:HUNT"
```

Answer (score -1):

This script removes any white space (multiple spaces, tabs, returns, etc) between words and trims:

```
// Trims & replaces any wihtespacing to single space between words
String.prototype.clearExtraSpace = function(){
  var _trimLeft  = /^\s+/,
      _trimRight = /\s+$/,
      _multiple  = /\s+/g;

  return this.replace(_trimLeft, '').replace(_trimRight, '').replace(_multiple, ' ');
};
```

Comment: Why would you `replace` _twice_ when you can `.trim()`?

Answer (score -1):

' mouse pointer  touch '.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|(\s)+/g, "$1") should do the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Using nodepad++ function,  below regex works fine for me,

Find: `{1}\K\s+`
Replace:`leave it empty`

Answer (score -2):

```
let nameCorrection = function (str) {
  let strPerfect = str.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
  let strSmall = strPerfect.toLowerCase();
  let arrSmall = strSmall.split(" ");
  let arrCapital = [];
  for (let x of arrSmall.values()) {
    arrCapital.push(x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1));
  }

  let result = arrCapital.join(" ");
  console.log(result);
};
nameCorrection("Pradeep kumar dHital");
```

Comment: the second line of code is helping to replace the multiple white space with just one. 
and the trim method at the end trims the white space out if there is any at the beginning of the string or at the end

Comment: I mean, this is not your notebook. Title-casing is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score -2):

`def removeblanks(text): return re.sub(r'\s\s+'," ",text)`
I was working on a large textual data with a lot of duplicate spaces.
The above RE worked for me. All the duplicate blank spaces were replaced by a single space.