# Remove all multiple spaces in Javascript and replace with single space

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

How can I automatically replace all instances of multiple spaces, with a single space, in Javascript?

I've tried chaining some `s.replace` but this doesn't seem optimal.

I'm using jQuery as well, in case it's a builtin functionality.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You could use a regular expression replace:

```
str = str.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
```

Credit: The above regex was taken from [Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Comment: This works too.
s = s.replace(/ +/g, " ");

Comment: Very true :) --inserts more characters--

Comment: `str= ''+str.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'')` is little better solution in case your str is `undefinied` or `NaN` :)

Comment: i'm reading data in from a txt file (via AJAX), and @InfinitiesLoop regex worked fine but Josiah's didn't

Comment: This didnt work for me. However @redexp did.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but this solution did not worked for me and I used Underscore String's clean() function instead. https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#cleanstring--string

Comment: Might be usefull: string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); it includes all whitespaces, not only double space. Also tabs, newlines etc. Read more: https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/javascript

Comment: This may be slow: https://jsperf.com/removing-multiple-spaces

Comment: try copy and paste "Search Results Web results ️ Get Emoji"  here https://www.regextester.com/95893 :D

Answer (score 60):

There are a lot of options for regular expressions you could use to accomplish this.  One example that will perform well is:

```
str.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' )
```

See this question for a full discussion on this exact problem: [Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 44):

you all forget about quantifier n{X,} http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_nxcomma.asp

here best solution

```
str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Comment: You could also cite [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) website for all sorts of regex flavors and full reference.

Comment: What's the improvement in using bracket quantifier over a simple +?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user `/\s+/g` also replaces single spaces (there is no need for this) but `/\s\s+/g` or `/\s{2,}/g` replace only multiple spaces.

Comment: @Aalex Gabi: sure, you're right, but, aesthetics aside, I doubt this will be noticeable in the vast majority of applications. A slight performance gain in veery large files, maybe? In all other cases, the plus is more convenient than the brackets, I'd say.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user I agree that the + is more convenient than the brackets. As for performance the single space is one third slower than the double space: https://jsperf.com/removing-multiple-spaces

Comment: @Aalex Gabi: Thanks for sticking numbers to the performance gain. That's definitively a heads-up for larger tasks. But still, forgive me for being stubborn, you won't notice in the majority of applications. ;)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

You can also replace without a regular expression.

```
while(str.indexOf('  ')!=-1)str.replace('  ',' ');
```

Comment: Works too... The question is : which is more efficient? This version or the regex version. I have a preference for regex as we never practice enough.

Comment: I don't know- if you have no matches, this method is more efficient. If you have a lot of matches, somebody is doing it wrong.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NickT/ScJKw/1/) that, I hope, emphasize the difference. It clearly outputs that regular expressions are, in all cases, at least as fast as loop versions. Not saying that loop version is bad, just pointing out that one must always consider maintainability and evolution of product.