# RegEx how to replace multiple spaces with a single one

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, whitespace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all multiple spaces in Javascript and replace with single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286874/remove-all-multiple-spaces-in-javascript-and-replace-with-single-space)

How can I replace, for instance this:

```
"  "
"   "
"    "
"     "
```

with

```
" "
```

How can I replace all the empty space characters with a single empty char using regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `myString.replace(/ {2,}/g," ")` should do it.

Comment: Better use `/ {2,}/g`, or you'll also replace all the single spaces with themselves.