# In JavaScript/regex, how do you remove double spaces inside a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string with multiple spaces between words:

```
Be an      excellent     person
```

using JavaScript/regex, how do I remove extraneous internal spaces so that it becomes:

```
Be an excellent person
```

Comment: They all seem to work, so I voted them up. Note, I added leading and trailing whitespace to your test string. http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/YhG3h/2/

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: I hope you were placing your wife *up on* a pedestal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 37):

You can use the regex `/\s{2,}/g`:

```js
var s = "Be an      excellent     person"
s.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Note: If you are attempting to remove multiple spaces from  (for example) a tab separated file, this will sometimes remove the tabs. That is the only difference between this answer and Yi Jiang's answer.

Answer (score 11):

This regex should solve the problem:

```
var t = 'Be an      excellent     person'; 
t.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
// Output: "Be an excellent person"
```

Answer (score 9):

Something like this should be able to do it.

```
 var text = 'Be an      excellent     person';
 alert(text.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '));
```

Answer (score 3):

you can remove double spaces with the following :

```
 var text = 'Be an      excellent     person';
 alert(text.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '));
```

*Snippet:*

```js
 var text = 'Be an      excellent     person';
 //Split the string by spaces and convert into array
 text = text.split(" ");
 // Remove the empty elements from the array
 text = text.filter(function(item){return item;});
 // Join the array with delimeter space
 text = text.join(" ");
 // Final result testing
 alert(text);
```

Comment: How is this different from accepted answer? Why your snippet completly different from code?