# How to remove duplicate white spaces in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Replace multiple whitespaces with single whitespace in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/removing-whitespace-from-string-in-javascript)

I have used trim function to remove the white spaces at the beginning and end of the sentences. If there is to much white spaces in between words in a sentence, is there any method to trim?

for example

```
"abc                  def. fds                            sdff."
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

try

```
"abc                  def. fds                            sdff."
 .replace(/\s+/g,' ')
```

or

```
"abc                  def. fds                            sdff."
     .split(/\s+/)
     .join(' ');
```

or use this `allTrim` String extension

```
String.prototype.allTrim = String.prototype.allTrim ||
     function(){
        return this.replace(/\s+/g,' ')
                   .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
     };
//usage:
alert(' too much whitespace     here   right?  '.allTrim());
   //=> "too much whitespace here right?"
```

[**edit 2023**] Pretty old answer. Here is a parser function to remove all multiple spaces (and *spaces* only, not [whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Whitespace#:%7E:text=Whitespace%20refers%20to%20characters%20which,JavaScript%2C%20and%20other%20computer%20languages.)) from a string, which removes the need for a regular expression.

```js
const line = ` hello     world
    how  are    you
     and bye again  `;

console.log(`[${removeDoubleSpaces(line)}]`);
console.log(`[${removeDoubleSpaces(line, true)}]`);

function removeDoubleSpaces(str, trimLinesToo) {
  let strResult = ``;
  let prev = ``;
  const strCopy = [...str];
  
  while(strCopy.length) {
    const chr = strCopy.shift();
    strResult += prev + chr !== `  ` ? chr : ``;
    prev = chr;
  }
  
  return trimLinesToo 
    ? strResult.split(/\n/).map(v => v.trim()).join(`\n`)
    : strResult.trim();
}
```

Comment: Got something to convert tabs and line breaks, too? I was looking for something that could compress code to ignore layout for functional comparison, basically to compare everything in two pieces of code except for the style they're written in.

Comment: `\s+` is for all whitespace, including tabs and line breaks.

Comment: Why the "g" in those regular expressions?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags

Comment: This doesn't deal properly with line breaks, as it replaces all multiples with a space.

Comment: @ChrisPeacock Sure. Use `.replace(/ +/g,' ').replace(/^\n +|^ +| +$|\n +$/gm,'')` if you need to keep the line breaks

Comment: Thanks @KooiInc. I tried that, there were still some problems, I ended up using this:
`.replace(/^[ \t]+/gm, '')
 .replace(/[ \t]+/g, ' ')
 .replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n')
 .trim()`

Answer (score 38):

```
var str = 'asdads   adasd    adsd';
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 10):

You can trim multiple consecutive spaces down to only one space with this Javascript:

```
var str = "abc def.  fds    sdff.";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

If you meant something other than multiple consecutive spaces, then please clarify in your question what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is JavaScript's string.replace() method.

If you want all whitespace removed, use this:

```
"abc def. fds sdff.".replace(/\s/g, '');
Returns: "abcdef.fdssdff."
```

If you want only double-spaces removed, use:

```
"abc   def.  fds      sdff.".replace(/\s\s/g, ' ');
Returns: "abc def. fds sdff."
```

If you want the space left after a period, use:

```
"abc def. fds   sdff.".replace(/[^.]\s/g, '')
Returns: "abcdef. fdssdff."
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following code part which used rejex in javascript to remove duplicate white spaces.

```
function trim(value) {
   var temp = value;
   var obj = /^(\s*)([\W\w]*)(\b\s*$)/;
   if (obj.test(temp)) { temp = temp.replace(obj, '$2'); }
   var obj = / +/g;
   temp = temp.replace(obj, " ");
   if (temp == " ") { temp = ""; }
   return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value.replace("  ", " ");
```

This should do the trick, it just replaces 2 white spaces to one, until you get only 1 white space.

Comment: That will only replace the first occurrence of two consecutive spaces. In JavaScript, `replace` behaves a bit "strange". If you want to replace all occurrences of a substring, you have to use a regular expression with the `g`lobal modifier. But in any case, replacing is not "recursive". The substitute is not checked again whether it can be replaced. Meaning, if your string contains three spaces, you will end up with two, not one.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the explanation. It seemed logical in my head :)

Comment: What about `replaceAll`?