# javascript setting textarea value with new line

Tags: php, javascript

i am new to php, javascript and web

I am having a situation => I have to set a value of text field on my client side, i pass value to my javascript function and it sets value as

```
 function editSubService(description){
      setVal("sub_service_description", description);
 }
```

and it sets the value right , but if there is new line in the text, it does not set the text field. how can this set that value of text field, its only not working if new line

Comment: Hi you can remove all unwanted spaces before set the value.. mystring = mystring.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,' '); [Click here to know more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/removing-whitespace-from-string-in-javascript)... May this will help you ....

Comment: here you are replacing it with space, i dont want to lose my data with new new lines, i did this <br/> but it didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

A `<input>` element with `type="text"` will not accept any newline characters. It is, by definition, a single-line field.
Use a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea) if you wish to have a multi-line input.

It's specification for `type="text"`, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input):

> text: A single-line text field; line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value.

Example:

```js
var area = document.getElementById("sub_service_description");
area.value = "This is some\ntext with a newline character";
console.log(area.value);
```

```html
<textarea id="sub_service_description"></textarea>​
```

Comment: it is a textarea but still not setting it

Comment: like this              <textarea name="sub_service_description" id="sub_service_description" value="" ></textarea>


------- how to set it

Comment: @mindFreezer Oh, textarea's work slightly different form input elements. I'll edit in a example, just a minute, please.

Comment: page does not exist