# How to remove white spaces in google docs spreadsheet cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am taking input in the form of a string in a google spreadsheet (through forms). I need to make sure that there are no white spaces before and after this string...

I've tried using Javascript command

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,' ');
```

but it doesnt seem to work here.

Please help

Comment: btw: a simple search will give you this..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163202/568414

Answer (score 1):

If your string is inside a google docs sheet, can you just apply the TRIM() function to it before importing to your application? TRIM() does exactly what you are looking for, plus removes duplicated intermediate spaces that trouble formatting.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

`s.replace(/\s+/g, '');`

**EDIT:**

`mystring = mystring.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');`

This will remove all spaces from the beginning or end of the string...

Comment: I know this is really old but shouldn't this be ```mystring = mystring.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');``` ? You have a space between the quotes and there should not be one, right?

Comment: I believe the question has change or the code in my answer was changed. It a very old answer and I hardly believe I gave an a simple answer that wasn't correct in this simple question. I will change it anyway, so people won't do a mistake. Thanks for watching