# Compare two strings using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm not sure what I'm missing so thought I'd throw this up here. Below is an `.ajaxComplete` method that is not working correctly. I need to compare the URL the action is coming from with the URL from the action I want this code to be executed after.

This is an ASP MVC site, so I use the helper to grab the URL from the appropriate controller action. I then use the `settings` object to determine where the URL from the source of the current Ajax call (I have a couple on this page so need to use this to differentiate).

As you can see from the screen shot, both the `url` variable and `settings.url` contain the same value. I also set an alert to check for the length of each, and the alert comes back with a length of `35` for both.

However... this code routinely fails the `if` condition (I cannot get the `alert("here")` to fire). I'm relatively new to jQuery so I'm wondering if this is the correct way to compare two strings? FYI - I originally wrote the condition to be

```
if(settings.url == url)
```

however I could not get this to pass either.

```
//Tie completion of GetChannel Ajax call to execution of 
//getDrmTerritory instead of using .change event on 
//Market Segment drop down
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetChannel", "AgentTranmsission")';
    alert(url.length + " " + settings.url.length);
    alert("about to check");
    if (String(settings.url) == String(url)) {
        alert("here");
        var channel = $.trim($('#channelName').text());
        if ($('#AlignmentM:radio').is(':checked')) {
            if ($('#MailingZip').val() != "" && $('#MailingState').val() != "" && channel != "") {
                getDrmTerritory($('#MailingZip').val(), $('#MailingState').val(), channel);
            } else if (channel != "") {
                $('#territoryName').text("");
                $('#Region').val("");
            }
        }
        else if ($('#AlignmentL:radio').is(':checked')) {
            if ($('#LocationZip').val() != "" && $('#LocationState').val() != "" && channel != "") {
                getDrmTerritory($('#LocationZip').val(), $('#LocationState').val(), channel);
            } else if (channel != "") {
                $('#territoryName').text("");
                $('#Region').val("");
            }
        }
    }
    alert("end");
});
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is a screen shot of `(settings.url == url)` evaluated in Chrome's console

[image]

and here is the `alert` that tests `alert(url.length + " " + settings.url.length);`

[image]

Comment: Why not just compare `settings.url == url` ?

Comment: Your `settings.url == url` should work, you probably messed something in your tests.

Comment: alert(url === settings.url);  return true?

Comment: @couzzi he says he tested that.

Comment: @dystroy yeah, I saw that as I commented. Blarg.

Comment: Just ran `alert(settings.url == url);` and it came back as false. Posted a screen shot of this condition being evaluated in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a spelling mistakes in the URL

Please check it out

**Transmission**

**Tranmsission**

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but why don't you try checking them for whitespace... I'm not sure whether it would be counted as part of length.

I've had similar issues before and would be the next place I would check. This link might help: [Replace multiple whitespaces with single whitespace in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/removing-whitespace-from-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I did check for length and they came back as being equal.

Comment: Cool. My next guess would be hardcoding the value and seeing how that tests against `url` and `settings.url` to see which one is deviating from the expected string.

Comment: If i do a cut/paste of what is in the console up above for the `url` variable and compare that with `settings.url` it passes the condition. However, this is why I used the `String(settings.url) == String(url)` condition, and I'm not sure why that isn't working.