# javascript regex to remove whitespace fails, why?

Tags: javascript, regex, adobe-indesign

I use `text.replace(/\s/g, '')` to remove all whitespace characters from a String.

I'm trying this on a russian text. I do an `alert(text)` which shows me the correct string, but the replace function throws this error - `Bad Argument /\s/g`

I'm creating .jsx files for Adobe InDesign scripting. The replace method works for some strings but fails sometimes. Any idea why?

Thanks.

EDIT

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    // If there is no text for the current entry, remove it
    alert(arr[i].text);
    if (arr[i].text == undefined || arr[i].text === "")  {
        arr.splice(i,1);
        i--;
        continue;
    }


    var trimmed = arr[i].text.replace(/\s/g, '');
        if (trimmed.text === "") {
        entries.splice(i,1);
        i--;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: A regex to remove whitespace... just, _why?_

Comment: InDesign API returns blank paragraphs, @GrantThomas. I'm just checking if the paragraph contains no meaningful text I'll not output it. So, I'm trying to remove all whitespace and compare with a "".

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using .text( ) to populate the text objects. I learnt that this function converts space to non breaking space (character 160).

Had to strip that too...
    `text.replace(/&nbsp;|\s+/g)`

Answer (score 0):

My bad - this is my edited answer.

```
var str = "Hello this is my test string";
var newStr = str.replace(/ /g, '');

alert(newStr) // "Hellothisismyteststring";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/removing-whitespace-from-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

- You need to escape ("\\") if there are any regex special characters like $, ^, etc... in your **text**.

-Try to post the fiddle or paste the failing text, we can check the issue.