# Regular Expression to find whitespaces and replace with a dash

Tags: regex

I thought this might work:  `^['\s+', '-', "This should be connected"\w\s]{1,}$`

But something is wrong with it. Does anyone no of a regex that will place dashes between words while at the same time not placing dashes in front of the very first word or behind the very last word?

I also need to keep in mind that I don't want a dash before the first word or after the last word. And, sometimes I will only have one word so no dashes are required.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: So what should that thing at the first line be? In all languages I know regex look much different

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace multiple whitespaces with single whitespace in JavaScript string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/replace-multiple-whitespaces-with-single-whitespace-in-javascript-string)

Comment: Sorry guys new here and didn't expect to get comments so quickly. Apparently I have angered some people by seeming to ask the same question again but the truth of the matter is I have spent the last few days searching this site for a solution and have not found one so I posed the question here. As far as the language we are using, I am not sure but I did just pose that question to my support desk an should have an answer shortly.

Comment: I am still trying to get an answer to the question what language am I using. The tool I am using is www.import.io which allows me turn any website into a table of data or an API in seconds – no coding required. It uses regex and xapath to help refine and reformat the data it captures.

Comment: could you post an example along with the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you use is rather strange. Why do you use `^` and `$` anyway?

One can use the following regex:

```
s/\s+/-/g
```

`s` means you will **s**ubstitute an occurence. `g` means it is **g**lobal: all matches should be replaced.

Using a tool like `sed` or `perl`.

**Example with `sed`**:

```
sed -r 's/\s+/-/' < file
```