# Returning a String with whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the below string and I want to return the substring with the blankspaces in javascript.

How can I do this?

As of now I used the normal substring function but its giving me the result after removing the blankspaces.

```
var Sting="CREC                     20140615001CREC_GLOSS                                               18_0000033122                    GLO4265      SGLB201406152014090120140531 TESTFOREF       0000000000033122                8-1         EQTY      GB                            21419     ACTUALS   EUR000000000462098830          8738           N                                                                                                                                                                             C70390000501F              SQTY BUY 212102 49500.00@ 9.34                                                                        8738        8738                             "

var x= Sting.substring(1,27)

Result x= CREC 20
```

I don't want it like this, rather, I want my result to be

```
x= CREC                       20
```

Comment: isn't the expected result exactly what you have?

Comment: I think what he wants is only one space instead of a lot of spaces between the words/ids codes, whatever. In hindsight, SO's comment editing feature is dysfunctional.

Comment: @SaintLike - Seeing as how the OP is new, I'm guessing he didn't format the code/result exactly as he would have liked to in the question.

Comment: You need to substring from 0 to 27, right now it loses the C.

Comment: It does seem to return all the spaces for me

Comment: The spaces are there - I'm sure he is displaying them in a browser which shows them as a single space

Comment: I don't see how you're getting the first `C` in your result when you use `1` with substring which would start with `R`.

Comment: So the behavior of substring is like that only. Can you elaborate more to us what is your case. regex can be the answer for you question.

Comment: Passing 1 as the first arg to substring will exclude the first character, which has the index 0.

Comment: Hey Guys if you see the result that i have got has only 1 space between CREC and 20 i want it tobe displayed in a format where it comes with ~20 spaces in between. i am getting the values but not in the correct format.sorry i used a 0 not 1 string.substing(0,27)

Comment: You need to state clearly that this is not an issue with `substring()` removing the spaces, but that the spaces aren't shown when you display the string on a web page. If you skipped the substring bit you would still have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a browser thing - consecutive spaces are displayed as one. You might want to replace `' '` with `&nbsp;` and then it will display all spaces indiviudaly

```
x.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

Another way is to avoid displaying the string as HTML. For example the `alert()` function will show the correct number of spaces without the need to replace. Also displaying the string within a  `<pre>` tag should work fine too.

Answer (score 2):

I think Dobromir's interpretation of the OP is probably correct, and therefore a good answer.

If it is indeed a browser thing, then perhaps a better way to get it to display properly **without changing the string itself** is to style the HTML element with

```
white-space: pre
```

This will preserve the spaces like it does in a `<pre>` block.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Nice one about the CSS, I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

If your spaces are always the same length you could do:

```
x.replace("                     ", " ");
```

otherwise you can use a regular expression to replace multiple spaces with one:

```
x.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

as seen [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/replace-multiple-whitespaces-with-single-whitespace-in-javascript-string)

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP wants, which is to preserve the whitespace (which is already preserverd, but he has gotten it wrong somehow).

Comment: I am so confused by the ever changing state of this question. At the current edit Dobromir's answer is correct...

Comment: If that is the reason you're excused :)