# How to transform two or more spaces in a string in one only space?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript/jQuery, what is the best/fastest way to transform two or more spaces in only one space in any string of an input field?

**Possibly without regex, please.**

```html
<script>
function spaces() {
   var textInput = insertText.value;
   while (textInput.includes("  ")) {
     var textInput = (textInput.replace("  ", " "));
    }
   alert(textInput);
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="insertText" value="word1    word2">
<button onclick="spaces()">ok</button>
```

Comment: *"Possibly without regex, please.'* Why? That kind of arbitrary restriction *must* be accompanied with a reason for it. Regex is exactly how you do this.

Comment: This is one of those cases where I **know** there are many duplicates, but the SO search mechanism is just not up to the task of finding them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple whitespaces with single whitespace in JavaScript string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/replace-multiple-whitespaces-with-single-whitespace-in-javascript-string) - There are also solutions without regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is OP's reasoning, but when I started JavaScript, I didn't like to use regular expressions because they look terrible, make no sense to the uninitiated, and are never explained by the initiated (answers to this question and almost every other one on SO are a good example of this). I really only learnt regular expression syntax when I found [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), which explains regex syntax and I would recommend to the OP to make sense of these answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **regular expression** as the first parameter of `replace`. `/\s{2,}/g` will do.

```html
<script>
function spaces() {
   var textInput = insertText.value;
   // no need for a loop here
   var textInput = textInput.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ");

   alert(textInput);
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="insertText" value="word1    word2">
<button onclick="spaces()">ok</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and search for white space.

```js
function spaces() {
   insertText.value = insertText.value.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="insertText" value="word1    word2">
<button onclick="spaces()">ok</button>
```