# How to replace string characters with only one blank space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all "WUB" in a string with a blank space. The problem is, if I have 2 "WUB" in a row, it will return 2 blank spaces. How do only return 1 blank space if I have "WUBWUB"?

```
function songDecoder(song) {
    var replacedLyrics = song.replace(/#|WUB/g,' ');
    return replacedLyrics;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple whitespaces with single whitespace in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/replace-multiple-whitespaces-with-single-whitespace-in-javascript-string)

Comment: @SteveNosse, that question addresses a string that already has multiple whitespaces in it.  This question seeks to prevent such an occurrence in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/#|WUB/g` should be `/#|(WUB)+/g` for your purpose.  Do you also want to replace multiple "#"s with a single space.  Then you might want `/(#|WUB)+/g`

The parentheses group the target strings together, then plus seeks one or more repetition of the group.

If you don't want a space at the beginning or end of your string, that could be another regex function, but probably the most straightforward method is to use the .trim() function.  So:

```js
alert(
    songDecoder('WUBYOUREWUBWELCOMEWUB')
)
 
function songDecoder(song) {
    var replacedLyrics = song.replace(/(#|WUB)+/g,' ').trim();
    return replacedLyrics;
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm! but let say you don't want a space at the beginning or at the end for example "WUBTHANKWUBYOUWUB" to extract "THANK YOU"

Comment: Of course @marinafive.  Consider marking as an answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex `/(WUB)+/g` it will match 1 or more element in the parenthesis

```js
function songDecoder(song)
{
    var replacedLyrics = song.replace(/(WUB)+/g,' ');
    return (replacedLyrics);
}

console.log(songDecoder("hello world !"));
console.log(songDecoder("WUB"));
console.log(songDecoder("helloWUBWUBworldWUB!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to `.replace(/#|(WUB)+/g, " ");`.

This searches for as many "WUB's" in a row before replacing them with a blank space