# Replace multiple \n with 1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How do I replace multiple `\n`'s with just one? So if a user enters

```
blah 

blahdy blah



blah blah
```

I want it to end up looking like.

```
blah
blahdy blah
blah blah
```

I know I could loop through with a while() but would rather use a regular expression, since I believe it's more efficient.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
string = string.replace(/\n+/g, '\n');
```

As others have said, it replaces each occurrence of one *or more* consecutive newline characters (`\n+`) with just one.

The `g` effects a "global" replace, meaning it replaces all matches in the string rather than just the first one.

**Edit**: If you want to take into account other operating systems' line ending styles as well (e.g., `\r\n`), you could do a multi-step replace:

```
string = string.replace(/(\r\n)+/g, '\r\n') // for Windows
    .replace(/\r+/g, '\r')                  // for Mac OS 9 and prior
    .replace(/\n+/g, '\n');                 // for everything else
```

**OR** (thanks to [Renesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686433/replace-multiple-n-with-1-in-javascript/6686463#6686463) for this idea):

```
string = string.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/g, '$1');
```

If you know in advance what sort of text you're dealing with, the above is probably overkill as it carries am obvious performance cost.

Comment: As I said on the other answer: If the input comes from an application on Windows that uses default OS line endings, [or any other OS with CR+LF line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) this will not work, because the characters will look like: `\r\n\r\n\r\n`.  Notice there are no multiple `\n` characters in a row.

Comment: In your edit, `.replace(/(\r\n)+/g, '\r\n')` should be `.replace(/(\r\n)+/g, '\n')` so that the second `.replace()` doesn't need to deal with the `\r`.

Comment: @patrick dw: Not if the OP wants to preserve the original line ending format, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to preserve it, then you'd keep it the same.

Comment: @patrick I think the edit looks fine as is.  This is safer for *displaying* the resulting string correctly in the originating operating system, since it preserves line ending.  There is no conflict with the second `replace` because `\r\n` line endings have no repeating `\r` characters.  @Dan +1 for your edits.

Comment: @Dan thinking about the line-ending-preservation thing, what about `string.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/g, "$1");`?  It works pretty well in my tests.

Comment: @Renesis: I actually had a similar thought, but my RegEx-fu is weak and I forgot how you refer to the first captured group so I was like "Eh, screw it." But yeah, good call; that definitely *looks* a bit neater  (at least) than chained `replace` calls.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use a character class to replace **one or more `\n` or `\r` with a single `\n`**:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, "\n");
```

Test HTML:

```
<script>
function process(id) {
    var oldString = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var newString = oldString.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, "\n");
    return newString;
}
</script>
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
<button onclick="alert(process('test'));">Test</button>
```

**Please note:** In the modern web, and in most modern applications, a single `\n` line ending is handled gracefully, which is why I've used that as my replacement string here.  However, some more primitive applications on [CR+LF (`\r\n`) operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) will display all text run together without the full `\r\n`, in which case you could use [Dan Tao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686433/replace-multiple-n-with-1-in-javascript/6686450#6686450), which provides a solution to preserve line endings, or the following, which accomplishes a similar thing in one call:

```
string.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/g, "$1");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var blah = "blah\n\nblahdy blah\n\n\n\nblah blah\n";
var squeezed = blah.replace(/\n+/g, "\n");
```

Comment: If the input comes from an application on Windows that uses default OS line endings, [or any other OS with CR+LF line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) this will not work, because the text will look like: `\r\n\r\n\r\n`.  Notice there are no multiple `\n` characters in a row.

Comment: @Renesis you are correct.  I don't do a lot of development in Windows anymore so neglected that.  

@mazlix you should accept Renesis' answer as it's both correct and has an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex

```
xx.replace(/\n+/g, "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without the overhead of the JavaScript engine setting up a finite state machine to run the regular expression, you can do it with arrays:

```
s = s.split("\n").join("");
```

Comment: Interesting, you make it sound heavyweight to run regular expressions, but is there real-life evidence on performance differences?

Comment: Split and join are both O(n), with relatively little overhead, Matching a string to a regular expression is O(mn), m = number of states in the FSM, plus that needs to be set up. You don't need real world when the maths tells you otherwise ;)

Comment: I beg to differ, as the constants to those operations play very heavily in situations like this.

Comment: Well it's a case of whether the complexity of operations in the split and join (very simple procedures) outweighs the overhead in setting up and executing the regular expression or not. I know which I'd rather go for. Also note that n for the join is smaller than for the split, though the elements are bigger.

Comment: I think it's worth being aware of the options. +1

Comment: Cheers, it's also good to question everything as well. It's a shame people just pick the thing that works without looking deeper into it.

Comment: Except that it doesn't work, -1. And also I bet is slower on strings with large number of lines.

Comment: @Qtax, 1) It does work, I've done it many times - feel free to try it, and 2) Do you understand asymptotic notation?

Comment: @Griffin, http://jsfiddle.net/PyyCs/ And please feel free to demonstrate `s/\n+//g` vs `split("\n").join("")` performance (even tho a string replace would work much better).

Comment: @Qtax, +1 yes you are correct. In my haste I read the question as wanting to remove all linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the same for spaces with detailed examples: [Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space). Example:

```
var str = "The      dog        has a long tail,      and it is RED!";
str = str.replace(/ {2,}/g,' ');
```