# Regex to split at >2 spaces or tabs

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a a regex that matches 2 or more spaces, or tabs, basically a combination of `text.split("  ")` and `text.split("\t")`. How do I create it?

My attempt: (but it doesn't work)

```
text.split(new RegExp("[  |\t]"))
```

Edit: This splits at spaces/tabs but I need to split at 2 spaces or more..

```
text.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\s{2,}
```

You can try in this way...!
\s{2,} means 2 or more

I got this idea from this replace post [Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/akubed/1/edit

I agree with @Will comment - Add Tab space also

```
\s{2,}|\t
```

Comment: I was using this but it didn't worked for one tab. Had do switch to `\s{2,}|\t`. I guess it is correct, since i had only a single tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="This      is      test";
    String [] as=s.split("\\t{2,}");
    for(int i=0;i<as.length;i++)
    System.out.println(as[i]);
```

> This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest my function below.
It separates every word, independent from any amount of spaces/tabs.

```js
const filterWords = (text) => {
    const wordList = text.split(" ");
    let trimmedWordList = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < wordList.length; index++) {
        trimmedWordList.push(wordList[index].trim());
    }

    return trimmedWordList.filter(function (e) {
        return e !== "";
    });
}

console.log(filterWords("    This       is a demo      text"));
```