# How to make " " appear in the middle

Tags: jquery, html, string

How to make string "Review 1" with sequencial white spaces in the middle to be rendered as such. Please see the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/r3Mrv/) below.

```
<div id="target"></div>​

var name = "Review     1"
$('#target').html(name);​
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `string.replace`

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: Most browsers will trim multiple spaces, so you need to use `&nbsp;` for each one instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use one `&nbsp;` for every space

Comment: or replace .html() by .text()

Comment: @redwind why? That doesn't make any difference to how white-space is rendered

Comment: sorry,it's my mistake, .text() can render space without using &nbsp; but only once space.
if you want to render multi spaces you need use &nbsp; instead.

Comment: @redwind `.text()` or `.html()` has nothing to do with rendering but how the input is interpreted. With `.text()`, `"<span>hi</span>"` would literally make that text, with `.html()` you end up with a span element. If you use `.text()` for `&nbsp;`, then you literally get that text, if you interpret it as html, you get a [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) character.

Comment: @Esailija: cause in this case, SonOfOmer want to insert a text into a div, it's not content any html tag, so i suggest him use text(). I tested it on my browser i relized that text() function can render only once space.
sorry,i'm not good at EngLish, so, quite difficult for me to explain clearly.

Answer (score 7):

Change how white-space is handled:

```
<div id="target" style="white-space: pre;"></div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PHvVh/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiple spaces you can use the html encoded character for a space: `&nbsp;` (=non break space)

```
var name = "Review&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = "Review     1".replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");

$('#target').html( name );​
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.replace()` Give this a try:

```
$(function () {
    var name = "Review     1"
    $('#target').html(name.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;'));
});​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/t4jtJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `&nbsp;` like others have said. If the text is dynamic, use replace:

```
name = name.replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "Review     1"
name.split(' ').join('&nbsp');
$('#target').html(name);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `<pre>` tag:

```
$('#target').html('<pre>'+name+'</pre>');
```

checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8BJuB/