# PHP weird "spaces"

Tags: php, csv, removing-whitespace

I've a problem importing a csv file ... 
The following code gives me something like this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "" [1]=> string(23) "Entfernung " [2]=> string(19) "1.3042 km" }
```

As you see, the number of characters doesnt match with the real word ("Entfernung" doesnt have 23 characters...) ...

Deeper research shows me that somehow an "invisble" whitspace is after each character (like. " E n t f e r n u n g") ...

How can i get rid of this / or prevent it ?

The Code ($files = array with filenames):

```
 for ($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $handle = fopen($files[$i], "r"); 
        while ($proc_file = fgetcsv($handle,0,",",";")) { 
        var_dump ($proc_file); 
    echo "<br>"; 
}
```

Splitting for example "Entfernung" (=$proc_file[1]):

```
$test = $proc_file[1]; 
        for ($a=0; $a < strlen($test); $a++) {
            echo $test[$a]."-";             
        }
```

gives me

```
-E--n--t--f--e--r--n--u--n--g-- --
```

Comment: Pretty sure that means 23 bytes, not 23 characters.

Comment: is it all ascii characters?

Comment: You'd probably do better fixing the code that generates the CSV file.

Comment: a) I can't fix the file - its automatically generated by an android app
b) i think that these are ASCII characters (but im not sure)
c) i think it means 23 character ... 
$var = "ABC DEF"; 
--> string(7) "ABC DEF"

Comment: what do you mean by deeper research?

Comment: Those aren't invisible spaces, it's 2 byte character encoding. Is there an actual error or problem here, or you just didn't like the byte counts?

Comment: I want to process some these csv files. But only some parts of it - So i need/want to search with an if clause ...

Comment: What does `mb_detect_encoding` return for the strings?

Comment: What about regexp ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space
maybe this would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to iterate through the indexed array returned by fgetcsv and clear all the whitespace

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $handle = fopen($files[$i], "r"); 
    while ($proc_file = fgetcsv($handle,0,",",";")) { 
        for($proc_file as $key => $val) {
            $proc_file[$key] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and the rest are still there?

Comment: unfortunately ... yes ^^

Comment: what would happen if you removed all non-alphanumeric (keeping the .) preg_replace('/[^\da-z.]/i', '', $string);

Comment: Ehm ... another thing: preg_replace('/[^\da-z.]/i', '', $string); works ... but i need at least the ":" too ...

Comment: sorry for the belated response, preg_replace('/[^\da-z.:]/i', '', $string);