# Javascript how to unify blank spaces into 1 blank space

Tags: javascript, string, replace, trim

So i have a dubt

if for example i have:

```
var string = "The     String";
```

but i want string always to look "The String" (only 1 blank space in case of multiple sequenze of them)

how to do that in a clever way and dynamically, i mean there are many cases like these:

```
string = "This        String";

string = "This String    is           short";

string = "This is    the   string";
```

i'm totally dumb in regexp (not only on it) and i guess it is the only way uh?

Comment: Did you consider googling for `replace multiple spaces with one`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a regex to get all spaces and replace it with one

```
string.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
```

If you only want it to work on a space and not tabs, use this:

```
string.replace(/  +/g, " ");
```

In the regex world "+" means 1 and any more that follow it.  The "g" at the end means "global", or do it more than once.  Removing the g would replace the first string of spaces but not any others.  "\s" means all space-type characters which includes " " and tabs.

Comment: not worth answering. Your answer is in the duplicate I posted

Comment: @Demilmp should i go for your solution or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space solution? why does?

Comment: @sbaaaang In most cases it doesn't matter.  If you look at the second answer to the link you posted, someone benchmarked the queries in FireFox.  I updated my answer to have 2 "\s" and 2 " ", which appears to be twice as efficient.  If you go with what I changed it to, you should get optimal speeds (or very close to it).