# Merge Multiple spaces to single space; remove trailing/leading spaces

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I want to merge multiple spaces into single space(space could be tab also) and remove trailing/leading spaces.

For example...

```
string <- "Hi        buddy        what's up    Bro"
```

to

```
"Hi buddy what's up bro"
```

I checked the solution given at [Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space). Note that don't put \t or \n as exact space inside the toy string and feed that as pattern in `gsub`. I want that in R.

Note that I am unable to put multiple space in toy string.
Thanks

Comment: If you read my Q carefully at the end, you can create a toy string with multiple spaces and then reply to my Q. I said above that I'm unable to put multiple space in toy string as stackoverlfow removed that automatically from my query.

Comment: `gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", x, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Hi David, That works for me. But can you explain me what the pattern is doing exactly. i.e ^ *|(?<= ) | *$ it says, replace everything with space " " but *|(?<=)|*$? ? is it correct? how it solves my problem. I want to know.

Comment: See [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E+*%7C%28%3F%3C%3D+%29+%7C+*%24)

Comment: I voted to reopen.  This one is slightly more involved looking at leading, trailing, and multiple spaces.

Comment: @TylerRinker, the code I provided works perfectly fine in this case, so how isn't this a duplicate?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The answer you gave works but the guidelines for closing regard questions.  That question (I believed; though could be mistaken) was different (I can't find it now) in that it wanted multiple spaces and leading.  This asks for multiple spaces and leading/trailing.  Again I may have missed something in that previous post, but I didn't believe the 2 questions to be exact duplicates.

Comment: @TylerRinker, even if this is not exact dupe, the answer there solves this question, but whatever

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This seems to meet your needs.

```
string <- "  Hi buddy   what's up   Bro "
library(stringr)
str_replace(gsub("\\s+", " ", str_trim(string)), "B", "b")
# [1] "Hi buddy what's up bro"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.In fact i wanted only gsub part as I din't mean to replace B to b. Where I stuck was to find pattern for doing such thing. Could you please explain me meaning of \\s+ ?

Comment: @chandresh - `\\s+` means "one or more spaces"

Comment: Worth noting at this point that this is the only answer that addresses changing the upper case b in `Bro` to lower case, as is shown in the desired result of the question.

Comment: @RichScriven I don't need to lower case, how do I keep the case?

Answer (score 72):

Or simply try the `squish` function from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
string <- "  Hi buddy   what's up   Bro "
str_squish(string)
# [1] "Hi buddy what's up Bro"
```

Comment: A modern approach, as str_squish came out in 2018, and is hidden under str_trim

Answer (score 43):

Another approach using a single regex:

```
gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", string, perl=TRUE)
```

Explanation ([from](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl))

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s]                     any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Why not use a much simpler REGEX, like Adam Erickson's?

Answer (score 35):

You do not need to import external libraries to perform such a task:

```
string <- " Hi        buddy        what's up    Bro "
string <- gsub("\\s+", " ", string)
string <- trimws(string)
string
[1] "Hi buddy what's up Bro"
```

Or, in one line:

```
string <- trimws(gsub("\\s+", " ", string))
```

Much cleaner.

Comment: This doesn't depend on any external libraries, and also it's not a nightmarish REGEX like Tyler Rinker's. Wonder why don't you have more upvotes?

Comment: I also wonder why @heisenbug47 exactly duplicated my answer half a year later.

Answer (score 6):

The `qdapRegex` has the `rm_white` function to handle this:

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_white(string)

## [1] "Hi buddy what's up Bro"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also try `clean` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
library(stringr)
str_trim(clean(string))
#[1] "Hi buddy what's up Bro"
```

Or as suggested by @Tyler Rinker (using only `qdap`)

```
Trim(clean(string))
#[1] "Hi buddy what's up Bro"
```

Comment: You could do all from within `qdap` via `Trim(clean(string))`.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose no need to load any extra libraries as the `gsub()` of Base r package does the work.
No need to remember those extra libraries. 
Remove leading and trailing  white spaces with `trimws()` and replace the extra white spaces using `gsub()` as mentioned by @Adam Erickson.

```
    `string = " Hi        buddy        what's up    Bro "
     trimws(gsub("\\s+", " ", string))`
```

Here `\\s+` matches one or more white spaces and `gsub` replaces it with single space.

To know what any regular expression is doing, do visit this [link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) as mentioned by @Tyler Rinker.
Just copy and paste the regular expression you want to know what it is doing and [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using strsplit:

Splitting text into words, and, then, concatenating single words using paste function.

```
string <- "Hi        buddy        what's up    Bro" 
stringsplit <- sapply(strsplit(string, " "), function(x){x[!x ==""]})
paste(stringsplit ,collapse = " ")
```

For more than one document:

```
string <- c("Hi        buddy        what's up    Bro"," an  example using       strsplit ") 
stringsplit <- lapply(strsplit(string, " "), function(x){x[!x ==""]})
sapply(stringsplit ,function(d) paste(d,collapse = " "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.
It doesn't eliminate whitespaces at the beginning or the end of the sentence as [Rich Scriven's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25708190/12812277) answer
but, it merge multiple whitespices

```r
library("stringr")
string <- "Hi     buddy     what's      up       Bro"
str_replace_all(string, "\\s+", " ")
#> str_replace_all(string, "\\s+", " ")
#  "Hi buddy what's up Bro"
```