# Using PERL regex broke merge of two data.tables

Tags: regex, r, encoding, gsub

I can't reproduce this with sample data, so please bear with me for a minute.

I'm trying to merge two `data.table`s, say `DT1` and `DT2`; `DT1` is `fread` in from a .csv file (should be UTF-8, I specified such when I wrote it myself from LibreOffice Calc on Linux), and `DT2` was read from an .xls file with `readxl::read_excel`. Not sure the encoding of the latter but you can get the file [here](http://dpi.wi.gov/sites/default/files/imce/sms/xls/cs_2014-15_ChrSchsOpen.xls).

I tried matching on a regex'd version of one of the columns. The regex I used to clean the column in both tables was `gsub("[[:punct:]]|\\(.*\\)", "", id)`. The tables merged fine; however, to improve the matching, I realized I should also exclude leading, trailing, and duplicate whitespace (i.e., to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25734388/3576984) approach to white space cleaning), using the updated regex:

```
gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$|[[:punct:]]|\\(.*\\)", "", name, perl = TRUE)
```

However, doing so introduces a warning, and the quality of the match deteriorates:

> Warning message:
>   In `bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,`  :
>     A known encoding (latin1 or UTF-8) was detected in a join column. `data.table` compares the bytes currently, so doesn't support *mixed* encodings well; i.e., using both latin1 and UTF-8, or if any unknown encodings are non-ascii and some of those are marked known and others not. But if either latin1 or UTF-8 is used exclusively, and all unknown encodings are ascii, then the result should be ok. In future we will check for you and avoid this warning if everything is ok. The tricky part is doing this without impacting performance for ascii-only cases.

It appears that simply activating `perl` caused something to happen to the encodings and screw with my merge. I poked around in `?regex` a bit, and seems PERL treats separate encodings differently, but checking `Encoding` was no help -- `DT1[ , Encoding(id)]` and `DT2[ , Encoding(id)]` are both *all)* unknown.

Why might changing from POSIX to PERL regex have screwed up my merge attempt?

Comment: I think you can just use a TRE regex like this: `gsub("(\\s)\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$|[[:punct:]]|\\(.*\\)", "\\1", name)`. However, since `(` and `)` are punctuation, perhaps, you wanted `gsub("(\\s)\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$|\\([^()]*\\)|[[:punct:]]", "\\1", name)`?

Comment: @stribizhev that's similar to what I ended up doing. I'm more curious why using perl might have produced mismatched columns.