# Flattening text rows in to a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column and rows like this:

row1:

```
something here

another line here
and we are here


but we also have this
```

row2:

```
something here2

another line here2



and we are here2


but we also have this2
```

is it possible to remove the big spaces and flatten all text into one line? The output is something like this:

```
row1: something here another line here and we are here but we also have this
row2: something here2 another line here2 and we are here2 but we also have this2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this on your rows to remove carriage return and new line from your string :

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, "[\r\n]" , "")
```

x representing your string

Comment: The result from this isn't quite the desired result, words that should have spaces between them are pasted together.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to collapse all the white space into a single space. Something like this from this SO question ([Merge Multiple spaces to single space; remove trailing/leading spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707647/merge-multiple-spaces-to-single-space-remove-trailing-leading-spaces)) should give the desired result:

```
string<-"something here2

another line here2



and we are here2


but we also have this2
"

library(stringr)
gsub("\\s+"," ",str_trim(string))

##[1] "something here2 another line here2 and we are here2 but we also have this2"
```

**For a data frame:**

```
df<-structure(list(strings = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("something here\n\nanother line here\n\n\n\nand we are here\n\n\nbut we also have this\n", 
                                                             "something here2\n\nanother line here2\n\n\n\nand we are here2\n\n\nbut we also have this2\n"
               ), class = "factor"), strings_cl = c("something here2 another line here2 and we are here2 but we also have this2", 
                                     "something here another line here and we are here but we also have this"
               )), .Names = c("strings", "strings_cl"), row.names = c(NA, -2L
               ), class = "data.frame")

df$strings_cl <- gsub("\\s+"," ",str_trim(df$strings))
```