# I have lot of spaces in my text after reading in R, how to eliminate them?

Tags: r

After reading my `.CSV` file in **R**, I have a lot of extra spaces in between. How do I eliminate these?

```
file = read.csv("filename.csv")
```

After reading the file, I get lot of spaces in between, how to remove in **R**?

```
a = data.frame(Answer = c("who doesn't like some appreciation now and then                                                                     all employees can give receive non monetary awards in the form of e cards please use the recognition awards and follow instructions there to send an e card want to send some appreciation my way          ")
```

In another situation, I have used below code to remove apostrophe such as `doesn't` so that I get `doesnt` but I am getting `doesn t`:

```
     a$Answer=gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',a$Answer)
```

Which is the correct way to remove apostrophe without getting a space?

Comment: Can you please tell me what this does?

Comment: I think this would work. `gsub("\\s+", " ", trimws(a$Answer))`. removing more than one space with only one space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge Multiple spaces to single space; remove trailing/leading spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707647/merge-multiple-spaces-to-single-space-remove-trailing-leading-spaces)

Comment: As for the punctuation issue, `gsub` takes the form `gsub(pattern, replacement, string)`. As you can see, in your `a$Answer=gsub('[[:punct:] ]+', ' ', a$Answer)` your replacement is a space, `' '`. If you want your replacement to be nothing--not even a space, use `a$Answer=gsub('[[:punct:] ]+', '', a$Answer)`. (I'm also surprised it's working with the space between the close brackets `] ]`. I would change to `a$Answer=gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', a$Answer)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Space Issue

For the space issue i think the **str_squish** does the job. It comes from the package *stringr*. (if you do no have it, make sure you installed it before you load the library)

```
install.packages(stringr)
library(stringr)
a$Answer= str_squish(a$Answer)
```