# Removing spaces in R

Tags: r

So I have a some data coming in where the spacing is not consistent for one particular column as a result I am not able to group them by this particular column.

```
testdata <- tibble::tribble(
  ~config,       ~construct, ~var,
  1, "This is line 1",   12,
  2, " This is line 2",   15,
  3, "This is line   1 ",   21,
  4, "This  is line 2",   12,
  5, "This is line 3",   12,
  6, "This  is line 4",   11,
  7, " This   is line 3 ",   21,
  8, "This is   line 4",   12
)
```

As you can see df above I am trying to group them by `construct` but then since the spacing is not consistent I am not sure how do I trim this in order to group them properly.

I have looked into `trim` but it appears to remove only head and trail space and not take care of the additional spaces in between. How can I remove such spaces in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge Multiple spaces to single space; remove trailing/leading spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707647/merge-multiple-spaces-to-single-space-remove-trailing-leading-spaces)

Comment: `tm::stripWhitespace(trimws(testdata$construct))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trimws` (to remove leading/lagging spaces) with `gsub` (to match 2 or more spaces and replace with single space) seems to work

```
gsub("\\s{1,}", " ", trimws(testdata$construct))
#[1] "This is line 1" "This is line 2" "This is line 1" "This is line 2" "This is line 3" "This is line 4" "This is line 3" "This is line 4"
```