# How to replace whitespace of varying length with one space?

Tags: r, string

How could I replace whitespace of varying length with a single space in R?

R has plenty of methods for replacing characters, e.g. `gsub`, tidyr, or the [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package. However, I cannot figure out how to best replace whitespace (with varying lengths) with a single `\n` space.

Here is a data.frame in R.

```
df = data.frame(column1= c("A B", "C  D", "E   F", "G    H", "I     J", "K      L", "M       N"))
```

Note that the number of spaces varies:

```
print(df)
#     column1
# 1       A B
# 2      C  D
# 3     E   F
# 4    G    H
# 5   I     J
# 6  K      L
# 7 M       N
```

My naïve approach would be to use `gsub()`

```
df$column1 <- gsub("[[:space:]]", " ", df$column1)
```

However, this doesn't change the varying length of spaces for replacement with a single space.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707647/merge-multiple-spaces-to-single-space-remove-trailing-leading-spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to use `+` i.e. one or more instead of just `[[:space:]]`

```
df$column1 <- gsub("[[:space:]]+", "\n", df$column1) 
df$column1
[1] "A\nB" "C\nD" "E\nF" "G\nH" "I\nJ" "K\nL" "M\nN"
```

If it is a single space, change the `\n` to `" "`

```
df$column1 <- gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", df$column1) 
df$column1
[1] "A B" "C D" "E F" "G H" "I J" "K L" "M N"
```

The OP's code with `[[:space:]]` result in replacing the space with either space or `\n`

```
> gsub("[[:space:]]", "\n", df$column1)
[1] "A\nB"             "C\n\nD"           "E\n\n\nF"         "G\n\n\n\nH"       "I\n\n\n\n\nJ"     "K\n\n\n\n\n\nL"   "M\n\n\n\n\n\n\nN"
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! I forgot about `"[:space:]]+"`

Comment: Fewer keystrokes with `"[ ]+"`

Comment: @IRTFM Yes, i thought so, but from my past experience, when the OP asks something with `[[:` and if we change it, they may not like it

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `str_squish`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   mutate(column1 = str_squish(column1))

  column1
1     A B
2     C D
3     E F
4     G H
5     I J
6     K L
7     M N
```