# How to remove a range of index-positions in the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "T  h  i  s     i  s     a              t  e  s  t";
//         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Now I want to remove this range: `[11 - 13]`, And I want this output:

```
var newstr = "T  h  i  s     i  s     a     t  e  s  t";
//            1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 14 15 16 17
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to replace multiply whitespaces with one? `str.replace(/\s+/g, '');`

Comment: This might be a replica of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: The solution by @dev-null is better to remove multiple spaces, however I'd like to correct it. Replace one or more space by a single space. `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` // Note, second argument, a space

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for the correction, just a typo from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var newstr = str.slice(0, 10) + str.slice(14);
```