# Codeigniter Regex deny multiple spaces

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

How can I replace a consecutive multiple space to a single space, and not allow space in the beginning and end of the string?

Here is my regex

```
preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i", $str)
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly, to deny or to replace? It is two different things.

Comment: Deny it if it is in the beginning or end of the string, and replace it to single space if it is in the middle of the string

Comment: how many spaces do you want to remove if it is in beginning or end(if there are more than one space)?

Comment: There should be no spaces in the beginning or end

Comment: simple solution :- `print(trim(preg_replace("/\s\s+/", " ", "      ab  c    def   ghi   ")));`

Comment: here is the link for what you need  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: Does this work for you: `"/^([a-z_\-]+[ {1})]?[a-z_\-]*)$/i"`?

Comment: Yes, almost, but if there's only one word and an extra space, it shouldn't be accepted

Answer (score 0):

Nothing difficult here:

```
if (!preg_match('~\A\s|\s\z~', $str)) {
    $str = preg_replace('~\s\s+~', ' ', $str);
} // else deny
```

If you want to check at the same time the string only contains ascii letters, underscores, hyphens or spaces with at least one character (as in your example), you can change the first pattern to:

```
if (!preg_match('~\A(?:\s|\z)|[^-a-z_\s]|\s\z~i', $str)) {
```

Comment: @aroncss: Really? Example?

Answer (score -1):

I have figured it out. It's

```
^([A-Za-z_\-]+[ {1})]?[A-Za-z_\-]*)+$
```