# Remove the whitespace before an element that is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am removing a `<span>` contained inside of a `<p>`. **Sometimes** there is a space **before** and **after** the `<span>`, which is causing an extra space when the `<span>` is stripped out. Note: I cannot change the HTML.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qftjntm/10/)

```js
$('span:contains("Name"),span:contains("name"),span:contains("[]"),span:contains("[ ]")').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="item">Hi <span class="name">User Name</span> , I see you need...</p>
```

So I want to remove the space only if the span is removed.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Answer (score 1):

After you strip out the `<span></span>` do another selection for the `<p></p>` content and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space) idea, `string = string.replace(/  +/g, ' ');`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space before and after the span. Put inside the span.

```
<p class="item">Hi<span class="name"> User Name </span>, I see you need...</p>
```

Will that work?

Comment: Nope - cannot change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

replace the white space with nothing, like so:

```
var str = "Test One";
str = str.replace(/ /g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You really have to watch out with regex/`.replace` approaches to this problem: it's easy to replace all kinds of text you don't want to touch.

An approach that could be a bit "safer":

- Locate the `<span>` you want to remove.
- Locate its parent element.
- Check if it is surrounded by text nodes (`nodeType == 3`)
- If there's a text node before the `<span>` you're removing, trim white space the end of its `nodeValue`.
- If there's a text node after the element, trim white space at its start.

Still, I don't believe the way you're processing your HTML and stripping out stuff will be very future-proof... Small changes to the content will bring up new problems.

An example (written to be clear, not concise):

```js
var spanToRemove = document.querySelector(".nestedSpan");
var spanParent = spanToRemove.parentElement;
var childNodes = spanParent.childNodes;
var childNodesArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i += 1) {
  childNodesArray.push(childNodes[i]);
}

var spanIndex = childNodesArray.indexOf(spanToRemove);
var textBefore = childNodes[spanIndex - 1];
var textAfter = childNodes[spanIndex + 1];

if (textBefore && textBefore.nodeType == 3) {
  // Trims both ends, would be better to just trim right end
  textBefore.nodeValue = textBefore.nodeValue.trim();
}

if (textAfter && textAfter.nodeType == 3) {
  // Trims both ends, would be better to just trim left end
  textAfter.nodeValue = textAfter.nodeValue.trim();
}

spanParent.removeChild(spanToRemove);
```

```html
<p>Text before <span class="nestedSpan"> This gets removed </span> , Text after</p>
```