# remove the whitespace from web-scraping <tr> tags nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a problem that is beyond me to solve. I am web-scraping a webpage more specific -its `<tr>` in nodejs, and am able to grab the content but for some reason the format is not ideal. It has a bunch of white-spaces when viewed in the console.log(). I tried the .trim() and .replace() but it did not really remove the spaces.I am guessing it is because the data was nested in the div and table format.  I don't know how to deal with it.

Also I tried to save it as array but all the output is not broken up it is just one block of data. If there is a answer to this question already please provide the link and disregard my post.

Here is a copy of the code

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = 'http://www.hcad.org';

var content = [];
var Tr = [];
request(URL, function(error, response,html){
if(error){
    console.log('Error happened: ', error);
}
if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Invaled response code returned: ', response.statusCode);
}
var $ = cheerio.load(html);


$('tr').each(function (i, element) {

    content = [];
    var a = $(this).prev();
    var trimmed_a = a.text();

    trimmed_a = trimmed_a.trim();
    var str = trimmed_a.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm, " ");
    var newStr = str.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/gmi, "");;

    content.push(newStr.trim());
    console.log(newStr.trim());
});



})
```

Comment: can you please add sample page you are trying this on?

Comment: It is in the code (URL)

Comment: Have you used 'replace' with \s to remove whitespaces? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: Yes I have and it did not give the desired results

Comment: Can you post sample of desired result and what you are actually getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing replace using whitespace as suggested in [Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space):

```
string = string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: I used a similar code and it did not do what I thought it was suppose to do sa.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "). I did not get the same result as the one you  posted.

Comment: \s will remove all whitespaces.
The site you use has a lot of spaces, not only carriage returns and line feed(\r \n) you seem to want to remove.