# Replace white space with a single space

Tags: regex, powershell

I am starting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space#1981366) example in JavaScript, and trying to do the same performance test.

I have

```
$string = 'RAM Statistics:     5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746=Peak'
$RegEx1 = '/ +/g'
$RegEx2 = '/  +/g'
$RegEx3 = '/ {2,}/g'
$RegEx4 = '/\s\s+/g'
$RegEx5 = '/ +(?= )/g'


Measure-Command {
    $newString = $string -replace $RegEx1, $null
}
Write-Host "$newString"
Measure-Command {
    $newString = $string -replace $RegEx2, $null
}
Write-Host "$newString"
Measure-Command {
    $newString = $string -replace $RegEx3, $null
}
Write-Host "$newString"
Measure-Command {
    $newString = $string -replace $RegEx4, $null
}
Write-Host "$newString"
Measure-Command {
    $newString = $string -replace $RegEx5, $null
}
Write-Host "$newString"
```

and I am getting very different times, but all return nothing, which isn't exactly useful. Where am I going wrong translating Javascript RegEx to PowerShell Regex?
FWIW, I want to keep things simple, so spaces only, no need to also replace CR and the like. The data is pretty simple, the formatting is just junk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell (by extension I think .Net in general) your modifiers/options are supposed to be at the beginning of the string in a construct like `(?smi)/ +` for example.

> Replace white space with a single space

```
$newString = $string -replace "\s+", " "
```

That should do it just fine if you want simplicity.

Consider this example using your regex string to show what you would be trying to match against.

```
"this is only a /    /g" -replace '/ +/g', "test"
this is only a test
```

A pair of literal forward slashes with at least one space separating them followed by the literal g.

Comment: So, seeing it makes sense, but growing the problem wasn't going to happen. RegEx messes with my head. Thanks! Now on to the next RegEx question of the day.