# Html is stripping empty space in string if there is more than one space between words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display a string like this on the html page

```
"Hello.    Hello"
```

When i pass the data from ajax to html, its displaying it as "Hello. Hello"
even though i pass it in the following way:

```
$("#tag").text("Hello.     Hello");
```

In html i have the div as defined below

```
<div id="tag"></div>
```

Comment: has an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space#1981366

Comment: @sid-m i dont want to remove the spaces if there are more than one space, i want to show it on the ui the same way.

Comment: then you can use the `pre` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your desired destination, in this case `#tag`, `white-space: pre;` in CSS. This will fix it (See snippet)

```js
$("#tag").text("Hello.     Hello");
```

```css
#tag {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "tag"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

use the `pre` element

```
$("#tag").append("<pre>Hello.     Hello</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML automatically removes whitespace, you can prevent this by using `&nbsp;` instead of a space. Read more on the non-breaking space [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

```js
var html = "Hello.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;World.";
$("#tag").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tag"></div>
```

If you want this to work without replacing the spaces yourself, you can also use a RegExp to do this for you:

```js
var html = "Hello.          World.";
let re = / /g;
$("#tag").html(html.replace(re, "&nbsp;"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tag"></div>
```