# How To Remove Multiple Spaces from String jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an excel spreadsheet that has 3 columns.

```
    1st        |    2nd    |    3rd 
----------------------------------------
  xxxxxxxx           x        xxxxxxxx
```

When I copy all 3 of those cells and paste them into my textbox I get a value that looks likes this:

[image]

I need to eliminate the spaces, but what I have researched isn't working.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MyTextBox").blur(function() {
        var myValue = $(this).val();
        alert(myValue);
        var test = myValue.replace(' ', '');
        alert(test);
        $("#MyTextBox").val(test);

    });
});
```

When I alert `test` it looks the exact same as the original and the value for `MyTextBox` isn't being replaced.

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0oot23g/) where I'm trying to replicate the issue, but in this instance, only the 1st space is replaced but the new value is populating into the textbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this what you want  https://jsfiddle.net/n0oot23g/1/ ?   `.replace(/  +/g, ' ')` will replace multiple spaces with only 1

Comment: you need a regex, try: `myValue.replace(/\s/g, '')`. `\s` is for space character nad `g` will replace all spaces

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you.  I didn't even think to use regular expressions!  Thank you!

Comment: This link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've changed your replace with a `regex`. This removes all the spaces

---

```
$("#MyTextBox").blur(function(){
    var myValue = $(this).val();
    alert(myValue);
    var test = myValue.replace(/\s/g, '');
    alert(test);
    $("#MyTextBox").val(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression would replace any number of spaces.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = 'Your string';
    var stringWithoutSpace = str.replace(/\s/g, '')
});
```