# Removing duplicate spaces from input

Tags: javascript, html, math

```
<textarea id="check" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>

<script>
var text = document.getElementById("check").value;
var lengthA = text;

    for (var i = 0; i < lengthA.length; i++) {
var space = " ";
if (lengthA[i] === space) {
    var next = lengthA[i] + 1;
    if (next === space) {
        lengthA.replace(lengthA[i], "");
       }
      }
     }

var length3 = lengthA.length - length2;
var words = length3 + 1;
</script>
```

Alright bois, me got a problemo! Im attempting to make a word counter through the law that each space equals a word (1:1). Im not sure why it is not working, it makes sense to me in my mind. I have attempted several alternatives and dwelled hours upon trying to fix this chunk. Thank you in advance to anyone that answers, even if it doesn't work! :)

**EDIT:** Regular expressions did the trick and replaced the incorrectly used `for loop` and if statements. Thanks

Comment: Since you already use the `replace` function in your solution, have you taken a look at this yet - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just the below -

```
var text = document.getElementById("check").value.replace (/ +/g, " ");
```

Not sure, why you would need a for loop to begin with.

/ +/ will more than 1 space
g will do all the changes throughout the text

Answer (score 1):

To remove the duplicate space, the following code

```
lengthA.replace(lengthA[i], "");
```

should be

```
lengthA = lengthA.substring(0, i) + lengthA.substring(i + 1);
// i should not increase
i--;
continue;
```

You misunderstand the usage of replace.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.replace()` of JavaScript to do this. This will remove not only space but also work for tabs, newlines etc.

**Usage:**

```
var string = string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
```

**So change below code:**

```
var lengthA = text;

    for (var i = 0; i < lengthA.length; i++) {
var space = " ";
if (lengthA[i] === space) {
    var next = lengthA[i] + 1;
    if (next === space) {
        lengthA.replace(lengthA[i], "");
       }
      }
     }
```

**To this:**

```
var lengthA = text.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
```

Reference here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace