# Teradata - Removal of multi spaces to single space

Tags: teradata, regexp-replace

I wanted to replace the multi spaces to a single space whenever more than one single space is found in the string. I was using this expression but it is not giving desired results. Is it possible that the data is having some extra non-ascii character than space.

What else am missing

I've tried below solution to update the column with below
TRIM(  REGEXP_REPLACE  (  'Report   the value of total personnel expense.', '( )+',' ',1 ,0, 'c'  ) ) ;

its not giving the desired result.

Actual result:Report   the value of total personnel expense.
Desired Result: Report the value of total personnel expense.

Comment: Have you looked at this one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space  It's for JS, but the search string may suit you.

Comment: Thanks ravioli, tried this TRIM(  REGEXP_REPLACE('Report   the value of total personnel expense.','[/\s]{2,}',' ',1,0, 'i'  ) ), but not working. With normal spaces it is working but i think something else is between "Report" and "the".

Comment: Hmm...can you create a fiddle and share it: http://refiddle.com/ ?

Comment: http://refiddle.com/olos

Answer (score 1):

`[ ]{2,}` will catch 2 or more space characters, then replace with a single space.

```
SELECT RegExp_Replace('Report   the value of total personnel expense','[ ]{2,}',' ');
```

Output: `Report the value of total personnel expense`

Comment: Thank you that worked in that example..can you make out whats happening here in this example .. i am not getting the desired result. SELECT 'Part A: Income   1. Interest income' as col1 , RegExp_Replace('Part A: Income   1. Interest income','[ ]{2,}',' ');

Comment: Not sure what your desired result is there?

Comment: SELECT RegExp_Replace('Part A: Income   1. Interest income','[ ]{2,}',' '); there are three spaces between Income and digit 1.

Comment: I think when we copy and paste from this webpage its working. But in the original table if i run that its not working. So I think some non printable characters on the play.

Comment: i did this is for the the spaces.. two came with ascii value of 32 and another one came as ascii 353 -> select ascii(' ');

Comment: This solution worked for me.  REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'[^[:ascii:]]','') and then replace the double spaces by a single space.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to replace consecutive whitespace with a single blank:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (x, '\s+',' ')
--'\s' matches blank, new line, tab, etc.
```

Or remove additional whitespace:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (x, '\s\K\s+','') ) ;
-- '\K' drops the previously matched characters from the match
```

I prefer #1 because all whitespace is replaced by a blank, while #2 will keep tab/new line if it's the 1st char in a match