# replace several spans <span>with one <span>

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I'm looking for a solution similar to
[Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)
but instead of space the question is about `<span>`. It doesn't contain additional attributes in it such as class. It's just exactly 6 symbols `<span>` (no spaces, no nothing).

As result, the string

```
"<span>The <span><span><span><span>dog <span><span>has</span> a long</span> tail, and it </span></span></span>is RED</span></span>!"
```

should be replaced to

```
"<span>The <span>dog <span>has</span> a long</span> tail, and it </span></span></span>is RED</span><span>!"
```

(please don't pay attention closing spans will be more, additional modifications are expected thereafter).

P.S. Yes, you're right, you may want to ask if 2+ consequent spans may have spaces in between, tabs or even new lines. Honestly - yes, but even without spaces, tabs, new lines the answer will be useful. Thank you.

Comment: It's the same as in the linked question. Just use a group `(?:<span>)+` to match multiple spans.

Answer (score -1):

Try out the following two replace methods (can you use them chained):
if  or  is repeated directly after another (twice or more often), replace that whole thing with just one expression:

```
.replace(/(\<span\>){2,}/g, "<span>")
.replace(/(\</span\>){2,}/g, "</span>")
```

By the way, regexr.com is a great place if you want to try out regex!